# Oracle select failes because of redefinition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dbms-redefinition

I have a plsql code in session1 that makes redefinishion using dbms_redefinition.

Another session that running a select query on the original table just failes when the finish procedure of the redefinition invoke.. with exception of no-longer-exists.

Isn't it the goal of this package to allow online-redefinition during someone still able to access the table???

Comment: AFAICT there's a moment between the start of the redefinition process and the moment when the process has created a snapshot when the table cannot be accessed. So a transaction running during this period will fail. Transactions (including updates) should continue accessing the old tale most of the time while the new table is being built. Look at [these tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_redefinition.htm).

Comment: Can you post your script to do the `DBMS_REDEFINITION`?  Don Burleson's wisdom aside, I don't think you should get ORA-08103 unless you drop the interim table too soon after the call to `FINISH_REDEF_TABLE` ends.

Comment: -- session 1

 declare

 v_target varchar2(40) := 't2_load';
 v_temp varchar2(40) := 't1';
 v_user varchar2(20) := 'dp99712a';

 begin


 dbms_redefinition.CAN_REDEF_TABLE(v_user, v_target,dbms_redefinition.cons_use_rowid);

 DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE (v_user, v_target, v_temp, options_flag   => dbms_redefinition.cons_use_rowid);

 DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE (v_user, v_target, v_temp);

 end;

 -- session 2

 declare

 v_cnt number;

 begin

 loop
 SELECT 1
 INTO V_CNT
 FROM T1
 where rownum = 1;

 end loop;

 end;
 "no longer exists"

Comment: 9000, 
according to those tips, the only moment of problem of access is only a moment of exclusive mode - it's mean select-operations are ok, isn't it?